# Personalization strings when sending to Campaign or Report

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

When performing a guided send from MC to a Sales Cloud Campaign, is there a way to access the Campaign Member ID via a personalization string so it can be saved in the SendLog?

Same when sending to a report? Can you access the columns in the report using AMPscript or do you have to import into a DE first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On v5, when doing Guided sends into a Report or Campaign you can access the following personalization strings: CampaignId, ReportId.

You can also create columns in the sendlog for these 2 and then you can retrieve the campaign member ID with ampscript using subscriberKey and either of these 2 strings.