# Personalization Strings for Salesforce Campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm sending an email to a Campaign from Content Builder. That is, I select Salesforce Audiences > Salesforce Campaigns > [campaign name] as the Audience when I send the email.

This works fine, but I can't figure out the required syntax for personalization strings (or attribute values for that matter).

I note that if I use the personalization string `%%First Name%%`, then Marketing Cloud uses the First Name value of the Contact (who is a Campaign Member in the selected Campaign). However, I can't figure out how to retrieve other fields on the CampaignMember Object. For example, I would like to use the CampaignMember Id.

I have seen [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171191/personalization-strings-when-sending-to-campaign-or-report#answer-171192) which states that the `CampaignId` value is available.

So, do I really need to use the [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](https://ampscript.guide/book/retrievesalesforceobjects) function to lookup the Id from the [CampaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm) object, based on `AttributeValue('CampaignId')` (where `ContactId == _subscriberKey`), or am I missing something?

It's also frustrating that there's no way to preview records when sending to a Salesforce Campaign (like you can do with Data Extensions). You just have to hit send and hope that it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do a send to a Campaign, a data extension is created in the root Data Extensions folder with the audience to be sent.  From there you can see the standard Campaign/Member fields available for personalization in the email for those sends.

[image: SF Campaign send schema]

Any data points not present will have to be retrieved with [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects**](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=retrievesalesforceobjects), as you suggested.

You can also preview against this data once a send has been completed.