# Marketing Cloud send to Campaign personalization

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign-member

Trying to show personalization strings from `Campaign` and `CampaignMember` object when doing a send to Salesforce Campaign via Marketing Cloud and later also pass these on to a Cloud Page.

Based on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212066/personalization-strings-for-salesforce-campaigns) discussion, it seems there is the root DE created with some basic attributes for personalization.

So it seems there are 2 options to go by, either using Synchronised Data Extension to `LookupRows` from `CampaignMember_Salesforce` data extension, or using `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` ampscript to retrieve the data directly from Salesforce during send time.

Right now I'm trying to retrieve it directly from Salesforce to start with, but none of the strings are getting any data after Email send, despite the AMPscript resolving without errors.

```
%%[

var @subscriberRows
set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
"CampaignMember", 
"CampaignId, ContactId, FirstName, Id, RSVP_Comment__c",
"ContactId", "==", _subscriberKey)

if RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 then /* there should only be one row */
  var @subscriberRow, @firstName, @Id, @ContactId
  set @subscriberRow = Row(@subscriberRows, 1)
  set @firstName = Field(@subscriberRow, "FirstName")
  set @Id = Field(@subscriberRow, "Id")
  set @ContactId = Field(@subscriberRow, "ContactId")
endif

]%%
```

The following is not giving anything on Email:

```
First Name: %%=v(@firstName)=%%
ID: %%=v(@Id)=%%
ContactId: %%=v(@ContactId)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need a single equals-sign as your operator in the [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects**](https://ampscript.guide/book/RetrieveSalesforceObjects) conditional:

```
%%[

var @subscriberRows
set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
"CampaignMember", 
"CampaignId, ContactId, FirstName, Id, RSVP_Comment__c",
"ContactId", "=", _subscriberKey)

if RowCount(@subscriberRows) == 1 then /* there should only be one row */
  var @subscriberRow, @firstName, @Id, @ContactId
  set @subscriberRow = Row(@subscriberRows, 1)
  set @firstName = Field(@subscriberRow, "FirstName")
  set @Id = Field(@subscriberRow, "Id")
  set @ContactId = Field(@subscriberRow, "ContactId")
endif

]%%
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It does compiles successfully with one equals-sign as well, but I'm still not getting any attributes to show up. Something is bit off with my script

Comment: Same problem here, the output is just empty

Comment: What do you get if you do this `%%=@RowCount(@subscriberRows)=%%`